# Redux: Dispatch actions in sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm creating a Reddit client on Redux and I have 2 store dispatches firing in the app:

```jsx
// App()
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    const stateMatch = window.location.href.match(/state=([^&]*)/);
    const codeMatch = window.location.href.match(/code=([^&]*)/);

    if ((stateMatch && codeMatch) || localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
        dispatch(fetchUser());
        dispatch(fetchSubs());
    }
});

...
```

However, I want `fetchUser()` to run and finish before `fetchSubs()` can begin, as the former currently seems to ruin API calls for the latter while it's running. How can I solve this?

Comment: can you show me fectchuser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `createAsyncThunk` you can do something like this:

```
  dispatch(fetchUser())
  .unwrap()
  .then((user) => {
    // do anything you want with user, or don't, also dispatch actions
    dispatch(fetchSubs());
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    // error in case of rejection inside createAsyncThunk second argument
    console.log(e);
  });
```

**Explanation**

Let's say `const thunk = fetchUser()`
so basically `dispatch(fetchUser())` is the same as `dispatch(thunk)`.

Redux's `dispatch` function returns whatever its argument (the action) returns.

So in this case, `dispatch(thunk)` returns whatever `thunk` returns.

`thunk`, based on how `createAsyncThunk` works, returns a promise that either resolves to fulfilled action, or the rejected action. (those actions that you receive in extra reducers).

This is how you can access those actions:

```
dispatch(thunk).then(fullfilledAction=>...).catch(rejectedAction=>...`
```

RTK library also provides a method called `unwrap`. Instead of those action objects I explained above, it lets you use the returned value from the 2nd argument of `createAsyncThunk`.

```
export const fetchUser = createAsyncThunk("user/fetchUser", async () => {
const user = await Reddit.getUser().then(val => {
    return val;
});

return user; // unwrap lets you use this instead of action objects.
})
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! If you could explain to me what's happening in this code step-by-step, that would help as well (curious about `unwrap()` in particular).

Comment: @DavyKamanzi edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with pure react and redux hooks

```
...

const state = useStore(yourStore) //use your method to read state 
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const checkValue = () => {
   const stateMatch = window.location.href.match(/state=([^&]*)/);
    const codeMatch = window.location.href.match(/code=([^&]*)/);

    if ((stateMatch && codeMatch) || localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

useEffect(() => {
    if(checkValue())
        dispatch(fetchUser());
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if(checkValue() && state.authState)
        dispatch(fetchSubs());
    }
}, [state.authState]);


...
```